# Deep Convolutional GAN (DCGAN) works really well on one set of data but not another

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, robotics, generative-adversarial-network, dcgan

I am working on using PyTorch to create a DCGAN to use to generate trajectory data for a robot based on a dataset of 20000 other simple paths.

The DCGAN works great on the MNIST dataset, but does not work well on my custom dataset. I am trying to tweak/tune the DCGAN to give good results after being trained with my custom dataset.

Below is an example of output from the GAN (top), along with example training data for MNIST (bottom) after 20 epochs. The loss for the Generator and Discriminator each plateau at around 0.7.

[image: Example prediction after training on MNIST]

[image: Example MNIST Training Data]

Below is the output for my custom trajectory dataset after a similar number of epochs. The top figure shows the output, and bottom figure shows the training set of the batch.

[image: Example output from GAN trained with path data]

[image: Training path data for the batch]

It is clear that the same GAN is much better at making predictions for the MNIST dataset then for my custom dataset. It is interesting to note that the Discriminator and Generator losses also plateau at similar values of about 0.7 for this dataset too. This makes me think that there is some limit to the network of how low the loss can go.

Discriminator Code:

```
class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, channels_img, features_d):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
        self.disc = nn.Sequential(
            # input: N x channels_img x 64 x 64
            nn.Conv2d(
                channels_img, features_d, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1
            ),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
            # _block(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding)
            self._block(features_d, features_d * 2, 4, 2, 1),
            self._block(features_d * 2, features_d * 4, 4, 2, 1),
            self._block(features_d * 4, features_d * 8, 4, 2, 1),
            # After all _block img output is 4x4 (Conv2d below makes into 1x1)
            nn.Conv2d(features_d * 8, 1, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=0),
            nn.Sigmoid(),
        )

    def _block(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding):
        return nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(
                in_channels,
                out_channels,
                kernel_size,
                stride,
                padding,
                bias=False,
            ),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.disc(x)
```

Generator Code:

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, channels_noise, channels_img, features_g):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            # Input: N x channels_noise x 1 x 1
            self._block(channels_noise, features_g * 16, 4, 1, 0),  # img: 4x4
            self._block(features_g * 16, features_g * 8, 4, 2, 1),  # img: 8x8
            self._block(features_g * 8, features_g * 4, 4, 2, 1),  # img: 16x16
            self._block(features_g * 4, features_g * 2, 4, 2, 1),  # img: 32x32
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(
                features_g * 2, channels_img, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1
            ),
            # Output: N x channels_img x 64 x 64
            nn.Tanh(),
        )

    def _block(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding):
        return nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(
                in_channels,
                out_channels,
                kernel_size,
                stride,
                padding,
                bias=False,
            ),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
            nn.ReLU(),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.net(x)
```

Training loop:

```
opt_gen = optim.Adam(gen.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE_GEN, betas=(0.5, 0.999))
opt_disc = optim.Adam(disc.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE_DISC, betas=(0.5, 0.999))
criterion = nn.BCELoss()

for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
    # Target labels not needed! <3 unsupervised
    # for batch_idx, (real, _) in enumerate(dataloader):
    for batch_idx, real in enumerate(dataloader):
        real = real.to(device)
        noise = torch.randn(BATCH_SIZE, NOISE_DIM, 1, 1).to(device)
        fake = gen(noise)

        ### Train Discriminator: max log(D(x)) + log(1 - D(G(z)))
        disc_real = disc(real.float()).reshape(-1)
        loss_disc_real = criterion(disc_real, torch.ones_like(disc_real))
        disc_fake = disc(fake.detach()).reshape(-1)
        loss_disc_fake = criterion(disc_fake, torch.zeros_like(disc_fake))
        loss_disc = (loss_disc_real + loss_disc_fake) / 2
        disc.zero_grad()
        loss_disc.backward()
        opt_disc.step()

        ### Train Generator: min log(1 - D(G(z))) <-> max log(D(G(z))
        output = disc(fake).reshape(-1)
        loss_gen = criterion(output, torch.ones_like(output))
        gen.zero_grad()
        loss_gen.backward()
        opt_gen.step()

        # Print losses occasionally and print to tensorboard
        if batch_idx % 100 == 0:
            print(
                f"Epoch [{epoch}/{NUM_EPOCHS}] Batch {batch_idx}/{len(dataloader)} \
                  Loss D: {loss_disc:.4f}, loss G: {loss_gen:.4f}"
            )

            with torch.no_grad():
                fake = gen(fixed_noise)
                # take out (up to) 32 examples
                img_grid_real = torchvision.utils.make_grid(
                    real[:BATCH_SIZE], normalize=True
                )
                img_grid_fake = torchvision.utils.make_grid(
                    fake[:BATCH_SIZE], normalize=True
                )

                writer_real.add_image("Real", img_grid_real, global_step=step)
                writer_fake.add_image("Fake", img_grid_fake, global_step=step)

            step += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

(Not enough reputation to comment yet, so I'll reply)

Since your code works fine on the MNIST dataset, the main problem here is that the trajectories in your training data are practically imperceptible, even to a human observer. Note that the trajectory lines are much thinner than the digit lines in the MNIST dataset.

Comment: I have an update. I tried instead with WGAN-GP and Conditional GANs, and have obtained good results, see below.

Training/real: https://i.imgur.com/FZ904Aq.png

Condition GAN output: https://i.imgur.com/VSPLML1.png

Comment: I'm glad to hear that! GANs, in general, are really tricky to tune :D

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).